# Github workflow failing on deployment to k8s

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, kubectl, setup-deployment

We have a k8s cluster (private cluster) on which we are hosting some apis. Since yesterday the workflow deployment from Github to the k8s stopped with the error:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
Error: Error: undefined
##[debug]Kubectl apply failed:Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.26.11/x64/kubectl' failed with exit code 1
```

It was working perfectly. We didn't do any updates or code changes.
This is the github workflow we are using:

```
deploy-to-k8s:
        needs: push-api-image
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout source code
            uses: actions/checkout@v3
            
          - name: setup kubectl
            uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3.0
            with:
              version: 'v1.26.11' # default is latest stable
            id: install
            
          - name: Set the Kubernetes context
            uses: azure/k8s-set-context@v3
            with:
              method: service-account
              k8s-url: CLUSTER_URL
              k8s-secret: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
          
          - name: Deploy to the k8s cluster
            uses: azure/k8s-deploy@v4.9
            with:
              namespace: default
              skip-tls-verify: true
              manifests: |
                k8s/deployment.yaml
                k8s/service.yaml
                k8s/ingress.yaml
              images: |
                ${{env.IMAGEURL}}:${{ github.sha }}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Things I would check - network - can it be reached from GH, does GH have the appropriate credentials to connection (have they been removed from GH or changed in K8S)?

Comment: You may just need to refresh the kubernetes credentials you're storing in github.